# Unable to convert object to string c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, arraylist

I am trying to extract values from `AraryList` but all i keep getting is `System.Object[]`...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReadDb readClass = new ReadDb();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list = readClass.ReadFromDb();

    string s = list[4].ToString();
    Response.Write(s);     
}
```

#### EDIT:

```
public class ReadDb
{
    List<string> rowList = new List<string>();

    public List<string> ReadFromDb()
    {
        Database db = new Database(); 

        try
        {
            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Blog", con);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                   reader.GetValues(values);
                   rowList.Add(values.ToString());
                }
                con.Close(); 
            }           
        }
        catch//(SqlException e)
        {
        }
        return rowList;
    }
}
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that `list[4]` is itself an array

Comment: r u getting any error/exception? If yes, then please provide stacktrace

Comment: What does `ReadDb.ReadFromDB` return? If the code in it is not too large - can you post it?

Comment: `list[4]` has got an object. as @AndersAbel asked, what does `ReadDb.ReadFromDB` returns?

Comment: it returns ArrayList. No error.

Comment: what element has that ArrayList got? Does the returned arraylist contain string? I mean does each of list[0], list[1],... list[n] contains string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `ArrayList`, use `Array<string>` instead. In .NET before 2.0 there were no generics and no way to make type safe collections. `ArrayList` is one of those original collections from the .NET 1.X times.

When writing new code, always use the type safe generic collections instead. `Array<string>` (in short form written as `string[]`) is such a type.

#### Edit

The problem is in this section of the code:

```
object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
reader.GetValues(values);
rowList.Add(values.ToString());
```

`values` is an array of objects. The `ToString()` method of `object[]` doesn't return the contents of the objects in the array, it just returns the name of the type. You have to change the call to `values.ToString()` into something that formats the values of the retrieved line into a string. For example:

```
rowList.Add(string.Format("Name: {0}, Address: {1}", values[0], values[1]);
```

Comment: Better to use `List<string>`.

Comment: but then i need to specify array size?

Comment: @Ingol: Then `List<T>` if what you need: generic, dynamic-sized container

Comment: I edited question, seems my method is sending System.Object[] as "value"??

Answer (score 2):

Use `List<string>` instead: generic (type-safe), dynamic-sized container

Comment: I edited question, seems my method is sending System.Object[] as "value"??